# Complex analysis question regarding Cauchy's integral formula and holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $U \subseteq \Bbb{C} $ be an open convex subset of $\Bbb{C}$ We also assume that $\partial U$ is smooth. We fix a point $z_0 \in U.$ Using Cauchy's integral formula, show that $$\lvert f(z_0)\rvert \leqslant C\sup\{\lvert f(z)\rvert \space | z \in \partial U\}$$
for any function $f$ which is holomorphic on $\bar{U}$.

So I know that I have to use the Mean Value Property but I can't figure out what to do from there. Any tips on how to approach this problem? Anything helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's false. Let $U$ be the open uppper half plane. Set $f(z) = e^{-iz}.$ Then $|f| = 1$ on $\mathbb {R}=\partial U$ but $|f| > 1$ in $U.$

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not just that $|f| > 1$ on $U$, but that $f$ is *unbounded* on $U$.

Comment: The answer is valid but I guess the author of the problem meant "$\partial U$ is a smooth closed curve".